# Can we get standard web output from Ionic 2 where we can upload to XAMP server and access it as a regular website?

Tags: ionic2

I'm new to ionic 2 framework. As I understood, ionic 2 made up with HTML and JS files and create native mobile apps. Since it is using HTML and JS files, is it possible to get output where we can use it as a regular websites ( where we can upload to XAMP server etc )

Simply, with one code we can have standard web output and Android / Ios output, is this possible with ionic 2 ?

If so what are the steps that I should follow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from ionic forum :)

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/can-we-get-standard-web-output-from-ionic-2-where-we-can-upload-to-xamp-server-and-access-it-as-a-regular-website/80119